# Paypal Connect button in Angular 9

Tags: angular, paypal

Need help in integrating paypal connect button within angular component. here is the documentation

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/connect-with-paypal/reference/button-js-builder/

The code provided is as follows, but doesn't understand how to integrate into the angular component.

```
    <span id='cwppButton'></span>
    <script src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/connect/api.js'></script>
    <script>
    paypal.use( ['login'], function (login) {
      login.render ({
        "appid":"api_id_goes here",
        "authend":"sandbox",
        "scopes":"openid",
        "containerid":"cwppButton",
        "responseType":"code id_Token",
        "locale":"en-us",
        "buttonType":"CWP",
        "buttonShape":"rectangle",
        "buttonSize":"lg",
        "fullPage":"true",
        "returnurl":"http://localhost:4200/sell/seller"
      });
</script>
```

I added the code in index.html but its not working.

Comment: "its not working" is a vague problem description. What happens when you run it? Have you tested it in a plain .html file opened independent of your web server?  Have you checked the dev tools console for error output? You can also share your sandbox API ClientID for others to reproduce, that is not private information.  Ensure the returnurl corresponds to one you configured in https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications